# Is there a picture in picture using spaces under OS X?

Tags: software-recommendation

Like picture in picture, I want a 'always in front' spaces in spaces. So if I am working or programming in one space, I can see another space that may be playing a video on the bottom right corner. Is there such thing?

Comment: You mean you want a window that stays in front of all other windows? If that's the case, I would probably change the title of your question to "How Do I Keep A Window Open In Front of All Other Windows?" It's sort of unclear as of now.

Comment: You could get the app that lets you use an iPad as a secondary display, and tape that to your monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see the contents of one space in another space, there is no such feature in Lion, and I'm not aware of any applications that may enable it.

All in all, such “feature”, if it existed, would have given me a bizarre feeling, akin to remoting into my own computer. Why would I ever want to do that? It would be impossible to control another space with a mouse (scaling issues) so watching a film would be a pain.

You want to code and watch a movie at the same time? (Sure it's a good idea?)
Great, **that's precisely what *windows* are for**.

[image: MPlayerX with Sublime Text 2]

<sup>([Sublime Text 2](http://sublimetext.com/2) running with [MPlayerX](http://mplayerx.org/) on top of it.)</sup>

Some media players (amongst them is MPlayerX, the most polished OS X player) always stay on top when playing so you won't have issues with window disappearing as soon as you switch the focus.

Finally, if you want a window **to stay visible regardless of chosen space**, right-click its Dock icon and assign it to **All Desktops** as advised by [Andrew](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/10496/andrew) in the comment to your question.

[image: Assign To]

Answer (score 2):

Check out afloat.  Link: http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/
It lets you "float" one window above others, and customize its appearance to a degree (eg. opacity).  May be what you're looking for, but I'm not really sure, as your question is a tad unclear, at least to me.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the PiP2 app on the app store